# Running cryptogen tool Windows 10

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, artifacts

I am trying to generate artifacts but i don't know how to run the cryptogen tool. It says to run command ../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml but I don't understand where to run it from

There is a file cryptogen but it is not a folder so can't get to that path.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cryptogen is a binary executable file used to generate certificates for basic learning.

In the directory where you have the samples checked out with  crypto-config.yaml

Execute this in command prompt. Replace the path variable with path to where you have installed cryptogen

```
<path>/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

***Please use a bash prompt to run the command.***